# Fetching Stocks from Yahoo directly into a Pandas (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, yahoo-finance

In my application I will be holding stock-info from the S &P500 index in a time-series, where I have defined a panda 'Stocks' with ticker symbols on first row (Index), and Company names on 2. Row named '0'

There are a couple of questions for you I am aware that this has been answered before. But I would to do it a little more complicated as I have 502 tickers from S &P500 index, that I need to fetch results from.

1. How do I rename my row 0 from 0 to 'Name'?
2. How can I make this panda a 3D panda that can also hold each days info pr. Each depth of the 3D panda, i.e. 2015.1.1 Is on the first sheet of the panda, and the next day I load 2015.1.2 Into the second sheet etc.? And what code would it take to make this happen?
3. How do I fetch stock-info about all 502 tickers from my panda 'Stocks'. The results should be appended from 3.row (1), and onwards down to whichever there are no more results

I have seen this codesnippet that might work, but I cannot determine how to make the constuction that loops through all the tickers of the panda and fills the info into the respective columns.

```
goog = DataReader("GOOG",  "yahoo", datetime(2014, 1, 1), datetime(2014, 12, 1))
print(goog['Volume'])
```

Comment: To get you started: 1. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html
2. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html
3. you will probably have to use a for loop

Comment: if you are looking for OHLC prices you should check out panda's `get_data_yahoo`: ` import pandas.io.data; pandas.io.data.get_data_yahoo(['AAPL','GOOG'],'1/1/2015').Open`

Comment: OK panda.Panel would be the 3D way of representing dates in a panda. However I think for my first Python project it might become too involved.

I'll have to go with Dataframes instead and save those for each day. IO will suffer as I will have to access HDD, but for now I think it would be the easiest solution. When -i will do any form of comparison between the ticker-symbols I will collect 2 things from each and compare in a new Dataframe. Could be done.

Comment: *********
However - nobody chipped in with some code that would fetch all 502 tickers stock-info in a while loop. Don't be shy!